# Properties Service does not work properly

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a function in Google Apps Script that is called by an app (appSheet), which, in short, aims to obtain events from several other calendars.

As a parameter, this function receives the number of months ahead that it should look for. Initially, and only at the beginning, I was saving the **starting date** and the **ending date** in the script's Properties Service, and then just reading these two data. It turns out that in a few executions later, I don't know why, the properties service, which should save the **end date**, started to "unintentionally change the date", below is an excerpt of the code as well as a printout of the bug:

```
function getEventByMeetingRooms(d = 7) {
  let meeting_rooms = listaSalasDeReunioes_();
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("xxxxxxxxxx");

  var cache_script = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  let start_time = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 1);
  let end_time = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + d, 0);

  cache_script.setProperty("start_time", start_time);
  cache_script.setProperty("end_time", end_time);

  var arr = [];

  if (meeting_rooms.length > 0) {

    for (let i = 0; i < meeting_rooms.length; i++) {
      console.log(meeting_rooms[i][2]);

      try {

        console.log("start_time: ", cache_script.getProperty("start_time"), " / end_time: ", cache_script.getProperty("end_time"));

        if(new Date(cache_script.getProperty("start_time")) > new Date(cache_script.getProperty("end_time"))){
            console.log("Erro ao processar evento: Data de fim é menor que a data de inicio");
              continue
        }
        
        var calendar = CalendarApp.subscribeToCalendar(meeting_rooms[i][2]);

        let eventos = calendar.getEvents(new Date(cache_script.getProperty("start_time")), new Date(cache_script.getProperty("end_time")));

        if (eventos.length > 0) {

          eventos.forEach((ev) => {
            arr.push([ev.getId(), ev.getTitle(), ev.getStartTime().toLocaleDateString(), ev.getStartTime().toLocaleTimeString(), ev.getEndTime().toLocaleDateString(), ev.getEndTime().toLocaleTimeString(), ev.getDescription(), meeting_rooms[i][2]]);
          });

        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        //return false;
      };

    }

  }else{
    console.log("O Array contendo as salas de reuniões veio vazio.");
  }

  if (arr.length > 0) {
    ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow(), ws.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(2, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Array de eventos vazios, sem atualização na planilha.")
  }
}
```

the end_time should only be, for example, 6 months ahead of the start_date, but a few executions later, it changes on its own to that print date:

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXUcP.png)

So far, my only suspicion for this bug is due to the large number of executions of this function by different people who use the app, even though I find it strange that the only value improperly changed in the Properties Service is the end_time.

Is there any other explanation for this behavior?

I tried to put start_time and end_time in constants outside the function, but the value in scripCache was still incorrectly changed

Comment: I would check your `d` variable. Often times `Dec 31 1969`/ Unix timestamp 0/Unix epoch appears  from an invalid date value or format.

Comment: `listaSalasDeReunioes_()` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getEventByMeetingRooms(d = 7) {
  let meeting_rooms = listaSalasDeReunioes_();
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("xxxxxxxxxx");
  var scrprops = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  let start_time = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 1);
  let end_time = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + d, 0);
  scrprops.setProperty("start_time", start_time);
  scrprops.setProperty("end_time", end_time);
  var arr = [];
  if (meeting_rooms.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < meeting_rooms.length; i++) {
      console.log(meeting_rooms[i][2]);
      try {
        console.log('start_time: %s end_time: %s',scrprops.getProperty("start_time"),scrprops.getProperty("end_time"));
        if(new Date(scrprops.getProperty("start_time")).valufOf() > new Date(scrprops.getProperty("end_time")).valueOf()){
            console.log("Erro ao processar evento: Data de fim é menor que a data de inicio");
              continue;
        }
        var calendar = CalendarApp.subscribeToCalendar(meeting_rooms[i][2]);
        let eventos = calendar.getEvents(new Date(scrprops.getProperty("start_time")), new Date(scrprops.getProperty("end_time")));
        if (eventos.length > 0) {
          eventos.forEach((ev) => {
            arr.push([ev.getId(), ev.getTitle(), ev.getStartTime().toLocaleDateString(), ev.getStartTime().toLocaleTimeString(), ev.getEndTime().toLocaleDateString(), ev.getEndTime().toLocaleTimeString(), ev.getDescription(), meeting_rooms[i][2]]);
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  }else{
    console.log("O Array contendo as salas de reuniões veio vazio.");
  }
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow(), ws.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
    ws.getRange(2, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Array de eventos vazios, sem atualização na planilha.")
  }
}
```